# Pandas return all columns after scaling

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns A,B,C,D

A, B are numeric columns C,D are non numeric

I only want to scale the columns A and B

**This is my code**

```
columnsToScale = ['A','B']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

x_train_new = scaler.fit_transform(x_train[columnsToScale])
```

After doing this my `x_train_new` only has columns A and B. I want it to have all four columns with A and B scaled and C,D just as it is. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

```
np.concatenate((x_train_new, x_train['C']), axis=1)
```

Comment: why did you edit your answer? the previous solution you provided worked for me
and also whats the purpose of using transpose here? and why use np.array?

Comment: @saranp ohh sorry I will edit it again, because in my laptop you need to transpose it first, glad that the first solution work, I changed my answer to the first solution, let me know if there is an error

Comment: @saranp if you want to convert it back to dataframe you can do this `pd.DataFrame(numpy_array, columns=['column_name_1','column_name_2'])`

Comment: btw how will you concatenate when row indices for x_train and x_train_new are different?
x_train_new  has rows starting from 0,1,2..etc  

x_train['C'] has random row numbers

Wouldn't it result in a mismatch if i straight away combine them

Comment: @saranp i dont think the order of the row is different, because you split the column and do the scaling after you did `train_test_split`